# Scala function overrides with lambda parameters

Tags: scala, methods, lambda, overriding

I'm trying to achieve a exposing a single method that has 3 overrides, differentiating on the input parameters - each of a lambda type - as per the following example:

```
//1:
def onAction(actionFn: =>Any) = ???
//2:
def onAction(actionFn: ()=>Any) = ???
//3:
def onAction(actionFn: (SomeEvent)=>Any) = ???
```

What I'm looking for is to be able to use the code with the following three variations:

```
//1: This would be used when defining some code inline
onAction { /* using the empty lambda block expression override */ }

//2: This would mainly be used when passing another function definition
onAction(()=> /* using the lambda expression override */ }
onAction(doMyCoolAction}
onAction(doMyOtherCoolAction}
def doMyCoolAction() : Unit = ???
def doMyOtherCoolAction() : Unit = ???

//3: Used when the "event type" is needed
onAction { e=> /* using the lambda expression with parameter */ }
```

Having the overrides like this doesn't play well together, specifically the 1.) and 2.) overrides don't play nice together... causing issues for the compiler to infer which of the function definitions to use.

**Is there any way / workaround that can allow me to use exactly the three example usages? (without adding additional "cluttered" syntax)**

**Note:** I've fiddled around with defining separate "ActionFn" class with implicit conversion from the three different lambda types... but no luck with that either:

```
def onAction(actionFn: ActionFn) = ???

class ActionFn {
    //....
}

object ActionFn {
    implicit def noArgLambdaBlockToActionFn(fn: =>Any) : ActionFn = ???
    implicit def noArgLambdaToActionFn(fn: ()=>Any) : ActionFn = ???
    implicit def argLambdaToActionFn(fn: (SomeEvent)=>Any) : ActionFn = ???
}
```

Any insights would be welcome, thanks :)

**Solution attempt:**
"Best solution so far", gives the error on usage scenario 3.):

```
//1:
def onAction(actionFn: =>Any) = ???
//2:
def onAction(actionFn: ()=>Any)(implicit d: DummyImplicit) = ???
//3:
def onAction(actionFn: (SomeEvent)=>Any)(implicit d: DummyImplicit) = ???

//3: Used when the "event type" is needed
//Error: "missing parameter type onAction({ e=>":
onAction { e=> /* using the lambda expression with parameter */ }
```

Comment: `: => Any` expands to `() => Any`. Why do you need these two overloads? Pick one.

Comment: Well, correct me if I'm wrong, but I can't use the usage example 1.) without the 1.) definition - and similar I can't use the usage example 2.) without the 2.) definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `=> Any` and `() => Any` variants erase to the same type, `Function0`. But you can add additional argument to one of those functions to disambiguate between them, and make it implicit to avoid cluttering call site. There's even a convenient `DummyImplicit` right in the standard library

```
object overloads {
  def onAction(actionFn: => Any) = "by-name"
  def onAction(actionFn: () => Any)(implicit d: DummyImplicit) = "lambda"
}

assert(overloads.onAction(1 + 1) == "by-name")
assert(overloads.onAction(() => 2 + 2) == "lambda")
```

Although you might get funny bugs just because somebody might mess up a parameter type, i.e. this is how it works:

```
assert(overloads.onAction { (a: Event1, b: Metadata) => a + b } == "by-name")
```

Comment: Hmm, nice one, I got one step further with this it seems, but now I'm getting issue with usage scenario 3.) - "missing parameter type onAction({ e=>" - not sure how to type code in the comment, so I updated the initial post.

Comment: @user506262 yes, 1 conflicts with 3 because Scala cannot figure out whether it's `{ e: SomeEvent => ??? }` and it should use case 3, or `{ e: SomeOtherEvent => ??? }` and it is case 1, so you will have to specify the event type on the parameter explicitly every time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I guess the current version is as good as it will get :)

Answer (score 1):

You have those problems because `=>Any` and `()=>Any` is same type.

So there is no solution for you.

I suggest you to name those function differently or remove one of them because according to your definition their behavior is identical.